# Macbook wont open ports

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to allow my phone to access a locally hosted website on my Macbook Pro as I develop it! its running 127.0.0.1 on port 5000 locally (i've been told that the 127.0.0.1 doesnt matter), and the IP that was given to me by my wireless router is 192.168.1.172. From what I've been told, I should be able to access the site from my phone on the same wireless network by going to 192.168.1.172:5000, however safari can never find the server! A quick port scan on my computer also shows that port 5000 isn't even open. How could I open this port so that I can access the site running on my computer?? Thanks so much for your help! Running the latest version of Mavericks.

EDIT: If it helps anything, the local version is running in a tango environment

Comment: You're better off asking this on SuperUser. StackOverflow is for programming related questions.

Comment: To answer your question, are you binding the server to `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: No I am not! So what your saying is instead of 127.0.0.1, you're saying just make it 0.0.0.0 on port 5000?

Comment: One of the reasons everyone likes to use tcp and http/https on standard ports is because they're normally open.

Comment: @GradyPlayer, `0.0.0.0` is certainly not `127.0.0.1`. See Gordon's answer.

Comment: @tangrs you are correct loop back is subtly different from the local address... but I don't believe it to be consistent, because apache bound to 127.0.0.1 wouldn't work with external connections if that argument were completely acurate.

Comment: @GradyPlayer If it's bound to `127.0.0.1`, it indeed wouldn't work with external connections. Binding to `127.0.0.1` would mean it would only serve requests to localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the web service to the IP address 0.0.0.0, instead of 127.0.0.1. 127.0.0.1 is the local loopback address, which means that if the service is listening on 127.0.0.1:5000, it will only be reachable from the server computer itself. If it's configured to listen on 0.0.0.0:5000 (sometimes written "*:5000"), that tells the OS that you want it to be able to receive connections on *all* of the computer's IP addresses (127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.172, and any others that happen to be assigned).

Comment: Fixed! For some reason when the server booted up (even though the makefile was telling it to bind to 0.0.0.0) it was binding to 127.0.0.1. Don't know why it was doing that but I figured it out with that knowledge. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your firewall settings?  System Preferences -> Security -> Firewall tab.  Then you need to open port 5000.

Comment: How would I open port 5000 from there though? I dont see an option for opening ports, only allowing applications.

Comment: OS X's firewall is based on the program listening for connections, not the port it's listening on. Is the firewall on? If not, this isn't the problem (unless you've configured another firewall somewhere). If the firewall is turned on, you'll need to add the server program to the list (click Firewall Options to reach it).